# Why is the monomer for this polymer drawn in this way?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am a bit confused about why the monomer for a particular polymer is drawn in a particular way.

Shown below is the polymer:

[image]

Shown below is the monomer for the polymer which the answer scheme gives:

[image]

I am a bit confused about why the monomer is drawn in this way. For each CH in the polymer, there is a CH3 molecule which is either above or below it. Why is it that, in the monomer drawn above, the CH3 is to the side of the CH. Isn't it above, so should be drawn above?

Comment: The "real" molecule is neither planar nor rectangular. So it is just a 2D projection of a 3D molecule.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't it be more accurate to put the NH part on the side?

Comment: I agree that placing the amino group to the left, as is usually done in drawing amino acids like the monomer you've given (which is alanine), is more helpful to the reader, but it isn't more or less accurate - the 2 drawings are equivalent. As MaxW says, in reality the bond angles around the central carbon would be approximately 109.5 degrees, rather than the 90 degrees shown.

Answer (score 4):

Schematic structural formulas are just formal notations, following structures of chemical bonds, but not actual 3D arrangement of molecules.

They can have multiple equally right and equivalent forms, as they all describe the same molecule, with focus on different aspects..

The one drawn above, with methyl on the left and amino group below, follows general organic chemistry approach of alanine being formally an aminoderivate of propanoic acid $\ce{CH3-CH2-COOH}$, i.e. 2-aminopropanoic acid.

The approach with amino group on the left and methyl group below is the biochemical approach, following the line of the peptidic structure. It takes aminoacids as formal derivates of the most simple aminoacid glycine $\ce{NH2-CH2-COOH}$, in our case 2-methylglycine.

So the latter approach is more suitable/illustrative in context of polypeptides, but the former one is not wrong.